# How to enable REST API on custom post type without Gutenberg?

Tags: php, custom-post-types, block-editor

I understand that you have to enable the REST API in order to use the Gutenberg block editor, because Gutenberg relies on it; however, I want to use the Classic Editor for a custom post type and still use the REST API. Is there another way to disable Gutenberg?

I am aware that setting `show_in_rest` to `true` in my `register_post_type()` function enables the REST API, but it also enables Gutenberg when I do.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: it would be more accurate to say that gutenberg is already enabled, but when `show_in_rest` is set to `false` it is disabled. You should be able to disable the block editor when registering your post type without needing to mention `show_in_rest`. I did notice your registration code is missing from your question though, I assume you've added `editor` in the supports section if you're seeing this behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code should do the trick.  You will just need to add the post type(s) to the line below.

```
function my_disable_gutenberg( $current_status, $post_type ) {

    // Disabled post types
    $disabled_post_types = array( 'book', 'movie' );

    // Change $can_edit to false for any post types in the disabled post types array
    if ( in_array( $post_type, $disabled_post_types, true ) ) {
        $current_status = false;
    }

    return $current_status;
}
add_filter( 'use_block_editor_for_post_type', 'my_disable_gutenberg', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!